# What can I do to stop the double popping of the print window when I click `print` in the web browser?

Tags: javascript, printing, event-handling

I have a challenge in my product I'm developing. I am developing an online receipt generator but I'm facing a challenge where I press the print receipt button and the print window appears. If I click `print` in this window, it prints the receipt but it pops another window with another receipt that was not asked for and with a new receipt number, since the receipt number is automatically generated from `001` onwards. The same challenge happens even when I click `cancel` in the print window.

I want to print only the requested receipt without popping another receipt because the numbering will disturb my client.

Here is the code snippet for the JavaScript function to generate the receipt number:

```
function generateReceiptNumber() {
  let receiptNumber = localStorage.getItem('receiptNumber');
  if (!receiptNumber) {
    receiptNumber = '001';
  } else {
    receiptNumber = String(parseInt(receiptNumber) + 1).padStart(3, '0');
  }
  localStorage.setItem('receiptNumber', receiptNumber);
  return receiptNumber;
}
```

Here is the function to print the receipt:

```
function printReceipt() {
  const receiptContainer = document.getElementById('receiptContainer');
  receiptContainer.style.display = 'block';

  const receiptNumber = document.getElementById('receiptNumber');
  const receiptDate = document.getElementById('receiptDate');
  const customerNamePrint = document.getElementById('customerNamePrint');
  const totalAmount = document.getElementById('totalAmount');

  // Generate the receipt number
  const generatedReceiptNumber = generateReceiptNumber();

  // Get the total amount in words
  const totalAmountWords = convertAmountToWords(
    parseFloat(calculateTotalAmount())
  );

  // Update receipt information
  document.getElementById('receiptNumber').innerText = receiptNumber;
  document.getElementById('receiptDate').innerText = receiptDate;
  document.getElementById('customerNamePrint').innerText = customerName;

  receiptNumber.innerText = generatedReceiptNumber;
  receiptDate.innerText = getCurrentDate();
  customerNamePrint.innerText = getCustomerName();
  totalAmount.innerText = calculateTotalAmount();

  // Print the total amount in words on the receipt
  document.getElementById('wordAmount').textContent = totalAmountWords;

  // Temporarily show the receiptContainer for printing
  receiptContainer.style.display = 'block';

  // Open the print window
  window.print();
}
```

The eventListener:

```
document
  .getElementById('printReceiptBtn')
  .addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    printReceipt();
  });
```

Where could I be going wrong in my code? And how can I stop this process of generating another receipt with the same content but different receipt number when I print or cancel the print process?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could provide a small demo that shows your issue. Your above code shows no call to the routine `printReceipt`.

Comment: Should I provide a link to the project?

Comment: Only if it is straightforward and easy to get running.

Comment: It easily runs
[https://jesar-enl.github.io](https://jesar-enl.github.io)  this is the link to the application

Comment: OK. I've found the issue with your code. Please accept and upvote if you found this to be of value to you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Taylor for the help. It's working now

Comment: No worries. Please upvote, too ;-)

Comment: How do I do that?? I need some guidance

Comment: Click the up arrow above my answer's score (currently zero). Thanks!

Comment: I currently have less reputation in drawer coz I'm new to this site and still earning more reputation to reach 15. I'm currently at 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your print dialog is running twice is because your code has **two** event handlers for the same button:

#1

```
<button type="button" id="printReceiptBtn" onclick="printReceipt()">Print Receipt</button>
```

#2

```
// Add event listener for the "Print Receipt" button
document.getElementById('printReceiptBtn').addEventListener('click', function (event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    printReceipt();
});
```

If you remove the first one, your code will run as you expected.

So, the button should now look like this:

```
<button type="button" id="printReceiptBtn">Print Receipt</button>
```

It is usually better to declare click handlers as you have in #2 rather than inline as #1, as the html should really just be for layout. Think of this separation as the same for using css files/ elements instead of using inline styles.

An extra problem you may have is that your document number increments by one each time the print dialog appears, even if the user clicks the cancel button. I've done a quick search and it seems that you cannot determine whether the page was printed or cancelled.